# Platform Independent Manifest to install and run apache2 or httpd

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise, puppetlabs-apache

I need to write a single manifest as `install-apache.pp` that will install

- `apache2` package if it is Debian based system or
- `httpd` package if it is RedHat based system

Below is the code; this works in CentOS but does not work in Ubuntu.

```
case $facts['os']['name'] {
  'Debian': {
    package { 'apache2':         
      ensure => installed,       
    }            
    service { 'apache2':     
      ensure => running,     
    }
  }
  'RedHat': {
    package { 'httpd' :
      ensure => installed,
    } 
    service { 'httpd':
      ensure => running,
    }
  }
}
```

So I made some changes as below, but am not sure why it is not working.

```
case $operatingsystem {
  'Debian': {
    package { 'apache2':         
      ensure => installed,       
    } ->             
    service { 'apache2':     
      ensure => running,     
      enable => true,        
    }
  }
  'RedHat': {
    package { 'httpd' :
      ensure => installed,
    } ->
    service { 'httpd':
      ensure => running,
      enable => true,    
    }
  }
}
```

Command used to execute:

> puppet apply install-apache.pp --logdest /root/output.log

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about what the problem is.

Comment: Have you considered using [the puppetlabs/apache module](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/apache), available from the Forge?  I mean, reinventing the wheel is great and all, but -- actually, no, it's not that great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are making use of the fact `$facts['os']['name']` which is assigned the specific operating system of the distribution and not the family of the distribution. That fact will be assigned `Ubuntu` on Ubuntu and not `Debian`. The fact needs to be fixed to `$facts['os']['family']`, which will be assigned `Debian` on Ubuntu.

You can also make use of [selectors](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_conditional.html#selectors) to improve this a bit more in addition to the fix. It is also recommended to  construct a dependency of the `service` on the `package` in that manifest to ensure proper ordering. Refreshing would also be helpful.

With those fixes and improvements in mind, your final manifest would look like:

```
$web_service = $facts['os']['family'] ? {
  'RedHat' => 'httpd',
  'Debian' => 'apache2',
  default  => fail('Unsupported operating system.'),
}

package { $web_service:        
  ensure => installed,      
}            
~> service { $web_service:    
  ensure => running,    
  enable => true,       
}
```